# How to hide a navigation bar in liferay theme based on the custom service response?

Tags: liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-velocity

I am working on lIferay 6.2 portal developement where I have requirement where i have to hide a navigation bar in liferay theme based on the response from custom service. and let me know is it possible to make only one web service call for checking this condition in liferay theme and use the same response in liferay portlets present in same page? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can write hook with Custom ServicePreAction implementation.
By overriding servlet.service.events.pre=com.custom.CustomServicePreAction

In your Custom ServicePreAction, you can make call to webservice and set some request attribute to define whether navigation should be shown or not.
In theme's vm you can get request attributes by $request.getAttribute("attrname")

Haven't tried this but hope this would help you.

Regards,